# Route value is added to querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to inject a link into some javascript in my cshtml page using the Url.Action helper.

I am expecting this output:

```
'/en-GB/Admin/Widgets/Edit/9c983e73-49a6-4f55-8fa1-e80e0bf35558?templateId=' + templateId'`
```

but this is what is generated:
    `'/en-GB/Admin/Widgets/Edit?objectEntityGuid=9c983e73-49a6-4f55-8fa1-e80e0bf35558?templateId=' + templateId'`

Here's the code:

```
function Load(newId) {

    var url = '@Url.Action("Add", "Widgets", new { area = "Admin", objectEntityGuid = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["objectEntityGuid"] })?templateId=' + newId;

    if (newId > 0) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("Edit", "Widgets", new { area = "Admin", objectEntityGuid = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["objectEntityGuid"] })?templateId=' + newId;
    }

    $.get(url,
          { "underlyingContext": underlyingContext },
          function (data) {
              $("#WidgetDialog").html(data);
          }
    );
 }
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your controller action method?

Comment: I could, but it doesn't even get that far. The link generated is invalid as shown above.

Comment: Ok, can you add the code of `RegisterArea` method? It should be in `Areas/Admin/AdminAreaRegistration.cs`. I think the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an `Area` named `Admin` and there's this file: `/Areas/Admin/AdminAreaRegistration.cs`. Try to change the `RegisterArea` method in `/Areas/Admin/AdminAreaRegistration.cs` to this:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "en-GB/Admin/{controller}/{action}/{objectEntityGuid}",
        new { action = "Index" }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Url.Action method tries to invoke the Edit action on your Widget controller with the input parameters objectEntityGuid and templateId.

The default format for this in MVC is indeed Controller/Action?parameterOne=someParameter&parameterTwo=someParameter.

If you have set up a custom route in RouteConfig.cs you can generate a suitable URL using

```
@Url.RouteUrl("RouteName", new { action="Edit", objectEntityGuid = 
         ViewContext.RouteData.Values["objectEntityGuid"] })
```

The route setup might look something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
         name: "RouteName",
         url: "en-GB/Admin/Widgets/{action}/{objectEntityGuid}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Widgets" }
     );
```